# How to call email to friend on list page

Tags: magento-1.9

I call Email to friend in `list.phtml` but I got error

**code**

```
<?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
     <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></span></span></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**error**

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::canEmailToFriend(Array
(
)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I founded an alternative solution, just load `sendfriend` model

```
$sendFriendModel = Mage::getModel('sendfriend/sendfriend');
```

Then use

```
<?php if ( $sendFriendModel->canEmailToFriend() ) : ?>
    <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></span></span></a></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

[refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061501/magento-accesing-sendfriend-module-from-category-page)

Answer (score 1):

`canEmailToFriend()` is function of class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.You cannot use at list page.SO you getting error this.

At list page,you should use below code instead of canEmailToFriend

```
$sendToFriendModel = Mage::registry('send_to_friend_model'); 

if($sendToFriendModel && $sendToFriendModel->canEmailToFriend()):
     // do whatever
     endif;
```

Comment: I tried this <?php $sendToFriendModel = Mage::registry('send_to_friend_model'); 
                    if($sendToFriendModel && $sendToFriendModel->canEmailToFriend()):?>
                         <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></span></span></a></p>
                        <?php endif;?> but not show frontend